# changing Json data structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file generated from the server side with this structure.

```
    "reports": [
    {
    "internalId": 60,
    "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
    "project": "pro1",
    "application": "app1",
    "decision": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17_60",
    "instanceName": "Report"
    },
    {
    "internalId": 62,
    "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
    "project": "pro1",
    "application": "app2",
    "decision": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
    "instanceName": "Report"
    },
    {
    "internalId": 65,
    "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
    "project": "pro1",
    "application": "app3",
    "decision": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
    "instanceName": "Report"
    },


   {
    "internalId": 62,
    "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
    "project": "pro1",
    "application": "app2",
    "decision": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
    "instanceName": "Report"
    }
```

I want to group the data by project so i want the new json stucture will be like this

```
"pro1": [
    {
    "internalId": 60,
    "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
    "application": "app1",
    "decision": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17_60",
    "instanceName": "Report"
    },
    {
    "internalId": 62,
    "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
    "project": "pro1",
    "application": "app2",
    "decision": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
    "instanceName": "Report"
    },
    {
    "internalId": 62,
    "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
    "project": "pro1",
    "application": "app3",
    "decision": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
    "instanceName": "Report"
    },


   {
    "internalId": 62,
    "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
    "project": "pro1",
    "application": "app2",
    "decision": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
    "instanceName": "Report"
    }
```

The problem is that I don't have access to the server side the create a service that generates me the structure i want so i must use the existant service.
when i use `_.groupBy` for exemple it doesn't give e the structure i want.
can any one help me or give some frameworks to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the below mentioned code into your server side return value place.

return "report :".json_encode('you_array_return_value');

Answer (score 0):

You should use `._groupBy` method from `underscore.js` library and it will work.

```js
let obj={"reports": [ { "internalId": 60, "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL", "project": "pro1", "application": "app1", "decision": null, "reference": "IMUPT17_60", "instanceName": "Report" }, { "internalId": 62, "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL", "project": "pro1", "application": "app2", "decision": null, "reference": "IMUPT17_62", "instanceName": "Report" }, { "internalId": 65, "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL", "project": "pro1", "application": "app3", "decision": null, "reference": "IMUPT17_62", "instanceName": "Report" },{ "internalId": 62, "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL", "project": "pro1", "application": "app2", "decision": null, "reference": "IMUPT17_62", "instanceName": "Report" }]}
var groups = _.groupBy(obj.reports, 'project');
console.log(groups)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use library like ramdajs to achieve this easily

```js
const data = {
  "reports": [{
      "internalId": 60,
      "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
      "project": "pro1",
      "application": "app1",
      "decision": null,
      "reference": "IMUPT17_60",
      "instanceName": "Report"
    },
    {
      "internalId": 62,
      "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
      "project": "pro1",
      "application": "app2",
      "decision": null,
      "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
      "instanceName": "Report"
    },
    {
      "internalId": 65,
      "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
      "project": "pro1",
      "application": "app3",
      "decision": null,
      "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
      "instanceName": "Report"
    },
    {
      "internalId": 62,
      "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
      "project": "pro1",
      "application": "app2",
      "decision": null,
      "reference": "IMUPT17_62",
      "instanceName": "Report"
    }
  ]
};



const byProp = R.groupBy(R.prop('project'));

const output = byProp(data.reports);
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is from ramdajs library http://ramdajs.com/ .  used to access that libraries functions

Answer (score 0):

```
var reports = [] // this is the array you get back from server
var result = {} // this will be the result of the grouping

// iterate over the result
reports.forEach(function(report) {
    // make sure you make a new object for every project
    if (!result[report.project]){
        result[report.project] = []
    }

    // add the line from the result to the result array under the project
    result[report.project].push(report)
})
```

this should do what you were after no need to add frameworks for this kind of thing